# put query_posts in 3 columns layout css

Tags: css, wordpress, multiple-columns, dynamic-columns

hi im trying to put a query_posts list in a 3 columns layout...

```
    <div id=”main”>
    <div id=”sinistra”>
    </div>
    <div id=”centro”>
    </div>
</div>
<div id=”destra”>
</div>

    <ul>
    <ul id="main">
    <style type="text/css">  
    #main { list-style:none; width:900px; }
    #main li { overflow:auto; margin:10px 0px; border-bottom:1px solid #E6E6E6; padding-bottom:0px; padding-top:0px; padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px; }
    #main li img { float:left; margin-right:5px; border:4px solid #EEEEEE;}
    #main li a { text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold; color:#1e292b;} 
    #main li p { margin-top:30px; }
    #main li {float:left;width:900px}
    #sinistra li {float:left;width:900px}
    #centro li {float:right;width:600px}
    #destra li {float:right;width:300px}
    </style>
    <?php
    query_posts( "orderby=&order=DESC&cat=28& posts_per_page=12" );
        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(90,120)); ?></a>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br>
    <p>blablaprova</p>
    </li>
        <?php
        endwhile; endif;

        wp_reset_query();
    ?>
    </ul>
```

i need the CSS to have 12 post of the same category divided 4|4|4 ordered by last edit
thanks for any help

Comment: It looks like you are working on a WordPress template and you will need to look at overriding some of the standard CSS styles that come with your template. Post some of the CSS rules that you have tried.

Comment: wait i edit the original thread and i put all the code with div and css

Comment: edited with the full html code sorry for sure is full of errrors xD